# SQLite, LIKE column name

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sql-like

What query could I use in sqlite to get the names of columns beginning with (for example) "thing" in a DB 
Such as if they were formatted like this:
"thing_column1"
"thing_column2"
"thing_data"
etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pragma_table_info()` with the table's name:

```
SELECT name 
FROM pragma_table_info('tablename')
WHERE name LIKE 'thing%'
```

You can use this query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS columns 
FROM pragma_table_info('tablename')
WHERE name LIKE 'thing%'
```

which returns only 1 column `columns` with a string value like `'thing_column1,thing_column2,thing_column3'` and you can use it to construct a `SELECT` statement in your application.

Comment: Is there anyway to put that directly back into a select statement?

Comment: @Xaeol this is a SELECT statement.

Comment: I meant something like SELECT (*your solution*) from table_name

Comment: @Xaeol This can't be done with pure SQL because SQLite does not support dynamic SQL. You can do it at the application level with a programming language.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using Python for this (as my app is written in Python anyway), thank you!